# Как изменить(активировать/деактивировать) флаг qcheckbox сразу при запуске программы?

Tags: python, pyqt, qcheckbox

У меня есть файл data.txt, где сохраняется состояние qcheckbox(true или false). Как мне при запуске программы установить состояние qcheckbox соответственно последнему сохраненному состоянию?
Не выходит как-то.
Думал, что если прочесть из файла "true" и написать тогда self.checkBox.isChecked() только для "true", то qcheckbox активируется.

```
# чтение файла с сохраненным состоянием qcheckbox
with open('data.txt', "r+") as b:
        all_wordsS = []#Список со всеми словами
        line = b.readline().split()#список из слов в строчке
        while line:
            all_wordsS.extend(line)#Вставляем в список с распа ковкой
            line = b.readline().split()#Заново считываем
        flag = all_wordsS[2]
        print(flag)

    # активация кнопок и виджета при запуске, если флаг был true
    if flag == 'true':
        self.checkBox.isChecked() #думал так можно будет
        self.btnEntFaceAdm.setEnabled(True)
        self.btnIdenFaceAdm.setEnabled(True)
        self.btnDeleteFaceAdm.setEnabled(True)
   # деактивация кнопок при запуске, если флаг был false
    elif flag == 'false':
        self.btnEntFaceAdm.setEnabled(False)
        self.btnIdenFaceAdm.setEnabled(False)
        self.btnDeleteFaceAdm.setEnabled(False)

   # отслеживание переключения флага qcheckbox и выполнение действия при изменении
    self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(
        lambda state=self.checkBox.isChecked(), no=1: self.selectBooks(state, no))

def selectBooks(self, toggle, no):
    if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
        #print('toggle=`{}`, поставили галочку{}'.format(toggle, no))
        if no == 1:
            #print('checked_{} -> галочка поставлена выполнилось действие'.format(no))
            self.btnEntFaceAdm.setEnabled(True)
            self.btnIdenFaceAdm.setEnabled(True)
            self.btnDeleteFaceAdm.setEnabled(True)

       # запись в файл состояния флага при нажатии(изменение на true)
            with open('data.txt', "r+") as b:
                ind = 'true'
                all_words = []#Список со всеми словами
                line = b.readline().split()#список из слов в строчке
                while line:
                    all_words.extend(line)#Вставляем в список с распаковкой
                    line = b.readline().split()#Заново считываем
                all_words.pop(2)
                all_words.insert(2,str(ind))

                with open('data.txt', 'w') as o:
                    for element in all_words:
                        o.write(element + '\n')
    else:
        self.btnEntFaceAdm.setEnabled(False)
        self.btnIdenFaceAdm.setEnabled(False)
        self.btnDeleteFaceAdm.setEnabled(False)

     # запись в файл состояния флага при нажатии(изменение на false)
        with open('data.txt', "r+") as b:
            ind = 'false'
            all_words = []#Список со всеми словами
            line = b.readline().split()#список из слов в строчке
            while line:
                all_words.extend(line)#Вставляем в список с распа ковкой
                line = b.readline().split()#Заново считываем
            all_words.pop(2)
            all_words.insert(2,str(ind))

            with open('data.txt', 'w') as o:
                for element in all_words:
                    o.write(element + '\n')
```

Comment: Вы вообще понимаете перевод имени метода `isChecked`? Не должен он ничего менять. [setChecked(bool)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#checked-prop).

Comment: Я уже понял, что они ничего не меняет, когда у меня ничего не получилось с ним) Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Devil Evil если вопрос не решен - опубликуйте [mcve]